# Regex to match anchor tags where link text is not same as href value

Tags: java, regex

I am looking Java compataible regular expression to match only anchor tags which don't have href value same as link text

e.g 1 (Should not be matched)

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.in">http://www.google.co.in</a>
```

e.g 2 (Should be matched)

```
<a href="http://www.google.co.in">Google</a>
```

I have tried the following but it is not working as intended

```
 <a(.*?)(?i)href\\s*=\\s*"([^"\\s]+)"(.*?)>(?=\\2)(.+?)</a>
```

Comment: Did anyone say "You Shall Not Parse HTML With Regex" here?

Comment: Welcome, new user. FYI: @Tunaki probably refers to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4136325

Comment: Use an HTML parser like JSoup; you'll have a _much_ easier time than using regexes.

Comment: I wouldn't use regex if I am programming in Java, I know there are lot of libraries to parse HTML. I am using Salesforce Apex (https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex) which is a JVM based language. I am just trying to put this logic in regex to avoid verbosity that comes if I use Pattern and Matcher classes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you really want to do this, you have to capture the value of href first and then check if it exists later :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "<a href=\"http://www.google.co.in\">http://www.google.co.in</a>";
    System.out.println(s.matches("<a href=\"(.*?)\".*\\1.*"));

    String s1 = "<a href=\"http://www.google.co.in\">http://www.google12.co.in</a>";
    System.out.println(s1.matches("<a href=\"(.*?)\".*\\1.*"));

}
```

O/P :

```
true
false
```

Comment: That is kind of obvious if I am processing each tag separately but it wouldn't work if I am processing the whole text at once.

Comment: Then you will have to look at jsoup

Comment: As a said in above comment I am using Apex. I wouldn't use regex if I have a provision to use Java libraries.